# #r shinyapps.io Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk: Failed to open file

Tags: r

I'm trying to deploy my app on shinyapps.io, but everytime I try in my console appear "Application successfully deployed to https:"... and in the app itself "disconnected by the server". 
This is what I found in my account

```
 No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419575+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419578+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      5: eval
2017-01-18T14:32:24.416074+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk: Failed to open file /home/shiny/applicazionemanager/registrazione1.csv.
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419574+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     12: fn
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419925+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:   Failed to open file /home/shiny/applicazionemanager/registrazione1.csv.
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419569+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419573+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     52: drop_get
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419579+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      3: eval
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419570+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     57: curl::curl_fetch_disk
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419575+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419571+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     56: request_fetch.write_disk
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419577+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      6: eval
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419578+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      4: eval
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419572+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     55: request_fetch
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419924+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419572+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     54: request_perform
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419577+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      8: tryCatch
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419579+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      1: local
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419573+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     53: GET
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419577+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      7: connect$retry
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419574+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     13: runApp
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419579+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      2: eval.parent
2017-01-18T14:32:24.419576+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:      9: tryCatchList
```

actually, there are other problems:

```
2017-01-18T16:17:29.641801+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’
2017-01-18T16:17:29.641802+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.642826+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2017-01-18T16:17:29.642829+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.642829+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     runExample
2017-01-18T16:17:29.642830+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.643956+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:
2017-01-18T16:17:29.643958+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.643959+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.665646+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.665648+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’
2017-01-18T16:17:29.665648+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.666164+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2017-01-18T16:17:29.666165+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.666166+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     box
2017-01-18T16:17:29.666166+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.869759+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2017-01-18T16:17:29.643959+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     removeClass, show
2017-01-18T16:17:29.870412+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.870414+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     filter, lag
2017-01-18T16:17:29.870415+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.871614+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2017-01-18T16:17:29.871618+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.871619+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2017-01-18T16:17:29.887706+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Package 'qcc', version 2.6
2017-01-18T16:17:29.869755+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.870408+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2017-01-18T16:17:29.869760+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.871620+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:29.887966+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Type 'citation("qcc")' for citing this R package in publications.
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124271+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124275+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124276+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124649+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124650+00:00 shinyapps[151746]: 
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124651+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:     serverInfo
2017-01-18T16:17:30.124651+00:00 shinyapps[151746]:
```

Comment: Well, the file `/home/shiny/applicazionemanager/registrazione1.csv` cannot be opened. Is that important for connecting ?

Comment: It's important for the purpose of my app i.e. a plot based on those data, but I don't know if the problem "disconnected from the server" is originated from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've used an absolute rather than relative file path for your csv data.

Maybe [this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-) will help?

Comment: In my server.R I read a .csv file, but before that I use a drop_get function to download the file from dropbox and to set the local file name I have to use the path, hence how can I do? drop_get("/app1/registrazione_1.csv", dtoken = token1, local_file = "~/applicazionemanager/registrazione1.csv" ,overwrite = TRUE)
r1<-read.table(paste0(directory,"registrazione1.csv"),header=TRUE, sep=",",dec=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,quote="")

Comment: My guess is that the local_file argument is a problem, specifically the "~/" part. It should work if you remove that and thereby make the path relative, but you should probably just be using drop_read_csv instead, which will download to a temporary directory and read it from there.


drop_read_csv("/app1/registrazione_1.csv", dtoken = token1)